# Ubuntu 16.04 dpkg configuration problem

Tags: 16.04, apt, upgrade, package-management, dpkg

I have lately upgraded ubuntu from 14.04 to 16.04 but i am incurring worse problems now when it comes to dpkg configuration, following is the error that i am getting

```
dpkg: error processing package hwdata (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
Errors were encountered while processing:
 hwdata
N: Ignoring file '50unattended-upgrades.ucf-old' in directory '/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How could i possibly resolve this error, there are some forums that discussed this error but nothing that which was suggested earlier worked out for me
kindly let me know what is the issue with dpkg configuration during the upgrade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your system is telling you exactly what to do here:

```
dpkg: error processing package hwdata (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
```

Simply re-install the package using `apt`, like so:

```
sudo apt --reinstall install hwdata
```

This should silence any DPKG errors and fix the package. If you need to, repeat this with any other inconsistent packages (if any).

Comment: I am facing another set of errors  now : W:     Target Packages (Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:55 and /etc/apt/sources.list:56 ... How should i resolve this ?

Comment: @DevanDev It's a warning, so it's not the worst to ignore. Go to `/etc/apt/sources.list` and find any duplicate lines and remove them. And if this answer solved your problem, please click the grey checkmark to mark it as "accepted" to get you some reputation.